# _Class.scss: Undefined variable "$font-family" in Sencha Touch theme

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, themes, sass, sencha-touch-2.1

I am trying to add a new customized theme to my app, but it is raising the following error when I am compiling on Compass:

> _Class.scss: Undefined variable: "$font-family"

I tried to change the `html,body` font in `_Class.scss` to `$font-family`, but it doesn't work. My Sencha Touch version is 2.2.1. How can I solve this issue?

```
// Let's start with the basics
$base - color: #CC0000;
$active - color: #850000;

// Buttons
$button-gradient: 'bevel';

// Lists
$list-bg-color: # eee;
$list - color: #333;
$list-pressed-color: # ddd;
$list - active - gradient: 'recessed';
$list - header - bg - color: #990000;
$list-header:white;
$list-header-gradient: 'bevel';

// Tabs
$tabs_dark_color: #000;

@import 'sencha-touch/default/all';

@include sencha-panel;
@include sencha-buttons;
@include sencha-sheet;
@include sencha-picker;

@include sencha-msgbox;
@include sencha-loading-spinner;

@include sencha-button-ui('action', #ffc801);
@include sencha-button-ui('decline', desaturate(darken(#b8a7a7, 10%), 5%));

.x-tabbar-dark .x-tab {
    color: white;
}
.x-list-header {
    color: white !important;
}
.x-list-round .x-list-header {
    color: #777 !important;
}
.x-tabbar-dark.x-docked-bottom .x-tab .x-button-icon {
    background: white !important;
}
```

Comment: Check your config.rb file.. The path specified inside the file should be correct.

Comment: This question has been asked already

[Question 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17751635/changing-default-blue-color-to-green)

[Question 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17588860/compass-compile-error-on-secha-touch-2-2-1-undefined-font-family-value-and-mix)

Comment: Thank you Viswa ,followed your answer for this ques.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17751635/changing-default-blue-color-to-green   works great

Answer (score 0):

This is a rather old post but for the sake of completeness. I ran into this issue yesterday. It occurs because you did not import the default theme variables.

You did import
`sencha-touch/default/all` but these are not the variables. The variable reside in `sencha-touch/default`

`@import 'sencha-touch/default';` should resolve the issue.

Answer (score -1):

create folder named stylesheets where you placed `config.rb`

I have created folder styles where I placed `config.rb` file

copy folder fonts from `touch\resources\themes\fonts` to `styles/stylesheets/` folder